# Convert PowerShell JSON to a CSV file

Tags: json, powershell, api

I have not used PowerShell much. I have an API request which returns JSON that I need to turn into a CSV or xlsx file.

```
$output = Get-SurveyParticipents `
 -url "https://orxsurveys.limequery.com/admin/remotecontrol" `
 -session $sessionKey `
 -id "5133965" `
 -start "0" `
 -limit "2" `
 -unused $False `
 -attributes ["completed", "usesleft"]

Write-Host($output | ConvertTo-Json)

{
    "id":  1,
    "result":  [
                   {
                       "tid":  "6",
                       "token":  "35ddmyQTlNpzLat",
                       "participant_info":  "@{firstname=Hsdfng; lastname=Gsdfh; email=gosdfdsfz.com}"
                   },
                   {
                       "tid":  "7",
                       "token":  "nQ_S838LjYT4mR6",
                       "participant_info":  "@{firstname=Ofdlga; lastname=Yadfdfa; email=olsdfdsfivska@axsdfdsfnce.com}"
                   }
               ],
    "error":  null
}
```

The participant_info doesn't look like a normal JSON structure.

Also I am unsure how to turn this JSON into a CSV. Something like:

```
$output | ConvertTo-Json  | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Scripts"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do both `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Json`. `Export-Csv` will convert a stream of powershell objects into a file containing CSV records.

Assuming the objects in the "results" array in your json output are what you want, you might try something like:

```
$output.result | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation foo.csv
```

You are correct to say that `participant_info` is not Json. You'll have to process this yourself. [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) might be helpful.